# What happened to convertEntities?

Tags: plugins, javascript

I was using the javascript function convertEntities in a plugin that worked great until recently and now the function seems to have vanished under 3.3 - Is there a substitute function I should be using?

I am tempted to just copy the function into my script - is there a reason that is a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`convertEntities` was removed because strings are passed to JavaScript via `json_encode()` now:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11520

Comment: To clarify the above, all I had to do was remove the convertEntities function from my script and everything started working as before. Thanks!! The codex is now outdated here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script , where at the bottom it says you need to use convertEntities to convert the object variable from string to HTML format.

Comment: Quick update ^ WP Codex has been fixed and no longer refers to convertEntities.